# prev/next elements for SplayTreeSet in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, binary-search-tree

I'm relatively new to SplayTree and Binary Search, but is there a way to cleanly get the next and previous elements in the SplayTree?

I'm working on trying to mimic a package from Javascript that used the JS SplayTree package that has the next and previous methods but can't seem to do this cleanly and am unsure if just doing the index-/+1 would work.

Answer (score 0):

`SplayTreeMap` has [`firstKeyAfter`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap/firstKeyAfter.html) and [`lastKeyBefore`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap/lastKeyBefore.html) methods.  Sadly, [`SplayTreeSet` currently has no equivalents](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35362).  I would follow the suggestions from the linked issue and use a `SplayTreeMap<T, void>` instead of a `SplayTreeSet<T>`.

Using `elementAt` with indices ±1 from the current index also should give you the right results, but in the absence of documented guarantees for runtime behavior, you probably should expect that each call might involve an O(n) traversal and would be inefficient.